# How to auto select Listview Item through Timer and put Listview Item text in Textview

Tags: java, android

I am applying data in listview with the help of given code.

```
 final ListView listNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNamesId);
    final TextView namesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesTexter);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNames1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
    listNames.setAdapter(adapterNames);
  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!namesText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                adapterNames.add(namesText.getText().toString());
                namesText.setText("");
                adapterNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

When the button is clicked, the data has put to the list view and
For scroll a listview i use this code that work fine.

```
   public void timerDelayRunForScroll(long time) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int h1 = listNamesId.getHeight();
                int h2 = listNamesId.getHeight();

                listNamesId.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(5, h1/2 - h2/2, 500);

            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }, time);
}
```

But i want to select every Listview Item one by one through timer count and put Listview Item text to a textview. My question is how can we select items of list view one by one with timer count and show the selected item text in a Textview.?